# Invision software error on wine

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, wine, winetricks

I was trying to install a Invision Studio software in wine in my ubuntu 20.04. But the installation failed, it says:

Please re-run this installer as a normal user instead of "Run as Administrator"

does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please edit your question and mention which software are you trying to install.